# Macro: How to apply same edits inside a {} in external files using command in LaTeX

Tags: macros

I am using Overleaf to edit some files.

Is it possible in LaTeX to set a command that links parts of a file to another? I mean to copy exactly everything inside a `{}` to another external file under the same project (apply all the changes there so I do not need to copy and paste that section from to the second file)?

For example, I have two `.tex` files named as `A.tex` and `B.tex`. What I expect is if in `A.tex` I have:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\MycommandA[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\MycommandA{This is a text}

\end{document}
```

and in `B.tex` I have is like

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\MycommandA[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\MycommandA{This is text}

\end{document}
```

So I want if I change `\MycommandA{This is a text}` in `A.tex` to `\MycommandA{This is a book}`, LaTeX automatically applies the same change in `B.tex`.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your comment. Sorry for my bad mistake. I have now edited my example using MycommentA based on your note. Could you please tell me how \input could be applied in my example? Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Many desktop editors support multi-file edits but I don't think Overleaf does, it is not really a latex question as latex never edits its source.

A latex way would be to have anyy shared texts or commands text just in one file, as in the example below.

### mycommands.tex

```
\newcommand\MycommandA[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand\textA{This is a shared text}
```

For small fragments like `This is a shared text` it is convenient to use a command as above. For larger fragments such as an entire section, you can use a separate file.

Then the text only appears in one place, and your `A.tex` and `B.tex` can look like

### A.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{mycommands}
\begin{document}

\section{Intro for A}% not shared

\MycommandA{\textA}% shared

\MycommandA{Text just in A but using the shared command}

\input{sharedsec}% shared
\end{document}
```

### B.tex

```
\documentclass{report}
\input{mycommands}
\begin{document}

\section{Intro for B}% not shared

\MycommandA{\textA}% shared

Some text just in B.

\input{sharedsec}% shared
\end{document}
```

### sharedsec.tex

```
\section{Something}
This text just appears once in the source but appears in A and B
```

Comment: Thanks. This will repeat textA from entire Mycommands.txt to other files as A and B. What I want is to repeat only SOME selective part of A (which is a long document) as \textA{} into B as \MycommandA{\textA} though. For example I want to change a paragraph in A and want it to be copied in B in a place that I put \MycommandA{\textA}. Any idea?

Comment: No you are only seeing that as your example was so small, with files A and B being the same. I'll extend the example a bit @Jackson

Comment: @Jackson see update

Comment: Thanks and appreciate it. In your example, my question is how to bring 
"Some text just in B" (not entire section, just this sentence directy into A???? So If I edit "Some text just in B." the changes appear in A as well (From B inside \begin{document} \end{document}

Comment: replace that line in b by \mytextzzz  then put \newcommand\mytextzzz{some text just in b} in mycommands.tex  then you can use \mytextzzz in file a wherever you want it to appear

Comment: Yep, I do not want to use mycommands.tex as B.text in my case is 400 pages. So I can't compy one by one to mycommands.tex. Iwant to link B to A directly without copying to mycommands.tex. Thank you so much for your time by the way.

Comment: @Jackson Sorry I have really no idea what you mean. Any text that is shared can either be in a command that is in a shared macro file or for larger sections in lists own shared file, the size of the documents a and b doesn't really make any difference. But I leave it here, hope you get something working.

Comment: It is clear. I don't want to use a shared text file. Anyway. Thanks. Good luck